# Search Facebook for posts with specific tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to search Facebook for **posts** with specific hash-tags using it's API?

I've spent some time trying to study the API documentation but failed to find any suitable solution. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

Meaning, a hashtag search is not possible, at least not anymore.